# One of the thread is getting stuck

Tags: python, multithreading

I have written a producer-consumer script, where I have two queues(say q1 and q2). There are two producers in the script which read the data from the q1 and right some processed value in q2, now there are another two consumers which read the value from q2 and print some value on the basis of some defined condition. All these four threads are running in parallel. I am facing an issue with the consumers where it gets stuck post reading all the value from q2. the condition to terminate the consumer is, if both the producer has been terminated and q2 is empty, but when I run this script it gets stuck with one of the consumer thread for example if consumer1 get completed then consumer2 gets stuck and vice versa.

can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!!

```
class WorkflowProducer1:
    def __init__(self,coord_q,wf_q):
        self.coord_q=coord_q
        self.wf_q=wf_q

    def wf_produce1(self):
        while not self.coord_q.empty():
            coord_id=self.coord_q.get()
            wf_id=workflow_finder(coord_id)
            if wf_id!='':
                self.wf_q.put(wf_id)
        if self.coord_q.empty():
            print("producer 1 finished")


class WorkflowConsumer1:
    def __init__(self,wf_q):
        self.wf_q=wf_q

    def wf_consume1(self):
        while not self.wf_q.empty() or thread1.is_alive() or thread2.is_live():
            wf_id=self.wf_q.get()
            workflow_validator(wf_id)
```